# Do Python's queue.Queue get/put methods hold the lock for that queue while blocking?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a conventional multithreaded producer/consumer pattern with a [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) in between. This implementation of queues is thread safe. The consumer can consume the data in two ways:

Blocking

```
while self.running:
    data = self.receiver_q.get(block=True)
    # do something with data
```

Non-blocking

```
while self.running:
    try:
        data = self.receiver_q.get(block=False)
    except queue.Empty:
        continue
    # do something with data
```

In the blocking method, the consumer waits until there is data in the queue. During this time, is the consumer holding the lock on the queue? I can't imagine a way for it to hold the lock while allowing the queue to have new data placed on it.

Also, is there a performance difference between the two patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) No, the consumer is not holding a lock; it's merely blocked until the request is satisfied, but the queue is still available.  If there are multiple consumers, then this one is in the pool of potential recipients; the resolution function will choose the order of satisfaction.

(2) Any performance difference depends on the implementation.  Don't ask us -- you have the foremost authority in front of you: your computer.  Use a test scenario of your choice, and the `timeit` facility.